# Proper translation for "active table"?

Tags: translation

For "Maximum number of active tables per W/W: 4", is "每位服务生接待已就座餐桌的最大数目：4" correct?

Does "acitve table" mean "the seat is taken"?

Comment: anyhow, 已就 (already) taken,就座 seat taken,         座餐桌 seat table (table with seats) n人座餐桌，e.g. n=4,6, table with n seats, maybe  已就座餐桌 is "(seat) table taken" or "table whose seats have been taken"

Comment: W/W? What does that mean? Is your question about a restaurant or a database?

Comment: Does "acitve table" mean "the seat is taken"? -- this seems an English language question to me, not related to Chinese

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good example of terrible sentences craft in mandarin, translate to English, later attempt to translate the terrible sentences back to mandarin.

It has nothing to do with taken seat or seat served, but serving.

It is pretty clear to say this in English :

```
Each waiters/waitress served : 4 tables max
服务生能接待的数目 ：最多4桌/台客人

Each waiters/waitress should only served 4 tables
服务生最多只能接待四桌/台客人
```

Just be careful when you read some "weird" mandarin and strange English translation. It is quite common as some restaurant owner refuse to consult people(not even amateur) to proofread their menu.

Comment: 其实翻译出来的是病句。在汉语里，服务生不接待“桌子”，服务生接待“人”。所以 "4 tables" implies "四桌客人（4 tables of customers）" 而不是“四张桌子”或者“四个餐桌”

Comment: @shuangwhywhy :fixed.